# Detail view, edit field: create input, buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a detail view for my object. There is only one field available for editing. When I click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button I want to hide text for field and show input with the <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.

```
// create kendo buttons 
$('#editGrnz').kendoButton({
    icon: "k-icon k-i-pencil",
});

$('.rt-field-cancel-button').kendoButton({
    icon: "k-icon k-i-cancel",
});

$('.rt-field-ok-button').kendoButton({
    icon: "k-icon k-i-tick",
});


$(document).on('click', '#editGrnz', function(e) {
    var $editButton = $(this),
        $parentContainer = $(this).parent(),
        $confirmEditButton = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-ok-button'),
        $cancelEditButton = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-cancel-button'),
        $editInput = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-edit-input'),
        $textContainer = $parentContainer.parent().find('.rt-detail-field');


    $editButton.hide();
    $textContainer.hide();
    $confirmEditButton.show();
    $cancelEditButton.show();
    $editInput.show();
});

$(document).on('click', '.rt-field-ok-button', function(e) {
    var $confirmEditButton = $(this),
        $parentContainer = $(this).parent(),
        $cancelEditButton = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-cancel-button'),
        $editButton = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-edit-button'),
        $editInput = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-edit-input'),
        $textContainer = $parentContainer.parent().find('.rt-detail-field'),
        id = $('.rt-content > #trafficId').val(),
        newTransportNumber = $editInput.val(),
        fixationDate = $('.rt-content > #fixationDate').val();

    //ajax call to save address   

    $editButton.show();
    $textContainer.html(newTransportNumber);
    $textContainer.parent().removeClass('text-muted');
    $textContainer.show();
    $confirmEditButton.hide();
    $cancelEditButton.hide();
    $editInput.hide();


});

$(document).on('click', '.rt-field-cancel-button', function(e) {
    var $cancelEditButton = $(this),
        $parentContainer = $(this).parent(),
        $confirmEditButton = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-ok-button'),
        $editButton = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-edit-button'),
        $textContainer = $parentContainer.parent().find('.rt-detail-field'),
        $editInput = $parentContainer.find('.rt-field-edit-input');

    $editButton.show();
    $textContainer.show();
    $confirmEditButton.hide();
    $cancelEditButton.hide();
    $editInput.hide();
});
```

This code is located in my view file. Now I have another view when will be the same logic. I don't want to copy this code. How to refactor it? I use `require.js` and may create a module for this functionality.

This is the working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6kxq8zgn/)

Comment: from your classes I take, you are using kendo-ui. is that correct? If yes, have you checked that kendo doesn't have a solution out-of-the-box for this?

Comment: @Vogel612: I haven't seen it.

Comment: I suppose you want something along the lines of [inline-editing (in grid)](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline) or [inline-editin (in editor control)](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/editor/inline-editing)

Comment: @Vogel612: Yes, I saw it. But this functionality is closed inside.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see the problem you have with that.. kendo-ui even does the ajax-call for you, so why are your [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]?

Comment: @Vogel612: because I'm not using grid in this case. This is detail view, not list.

Comment: Why not use the editor control then?? There's two inline-edit ways. The grid is but one of them...